# Setting up database for TeamCity in Windows 7

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I am trying to setup TeamCity 9.1 in my windows machine.
In the Database setup portion, I downloaded the sql driver and copied the 
sqljdbc4.jar file to folder "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.BuildServer\lib\jdbc" folder as mentioned in the instruction page.

But still I am getting this message upon clicking Refresh JDBC drivers

> The MS SQL Server JDBC driver is not found in the
>   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.BuildServer\lib\jdbc
>   directory.
>
> Download the driver from the Microsoft Download Center and follow the
>    instructions and place the driver jar file into the
>   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.BuildServer\lib\jdbc
>    directory on the server.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Did you correctly modify your database.properties file?  If you're running TC server as a windows service, make sure you stop the service and make the change and start it back.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when setting up TeamCity 9.1. At this point of the installation the folders `.BuildServer\lib\jdbc` didn't exist under `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`. I reinstalled TeamCity and installed it again but defined the data directory manually as `C:\TeamCityData`.
When the setup wizard asked for the driver I copied the `sqljdbc4.jar` file to `C:\TeamCityData\lib\jdbc` (This time it existed), clicked `refresh JDBC drivers` and it worked. Hope this would help you

Answer (score 0):

on a normal TeamCity Installation the JDBC jar file needs to be in the "C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\lib\JDBC\" folder where Program Data is a hidden folder in the C drive.

Once you drop the jar file here it should be detected. Let me know how it goes.

Cheers!